# Computational complexity of factoring univariate polynomials with positive integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I am interested in the computational complexity of the following problem.
Input: a polynomial p(x) with positive integer coefficients
Output: a factorization of p(x) into irreducible factors having positive integer coefficients themselves

Comment: This forum is for research level questions only. You should google for "LLL" (Lenstra, Lenstra and Lovász) or "Zassenhaus algorithm", or read a textbook on computer algebra (for instance the book by Von zur Gathen and Gerhard).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials

Comment: Thank you for your immediate reply, did you notice that I am not looking for algorithms that compute the factorization of elements of Z[x] but of elements of N[X] ... are you sure that LLL algorithms produce factors in N[x] ? I do not think so ... did you notice for example that over N[x] factorization is not unique ? ....